# Google PHP Client for Blogger API v3, uploading images in posts

Tags: php, google-api, blogger

i'm working with Blogger API v3 using Google Client for PHP. Using the following code i'm able to post textual content, but i want to upload images as well, so how am i going to integrate images api to post?

```
$posts = $bloggerService->posts;

    $NewPost = new Google_Service_Blogger_Post();
    $NewPost->setTitle("Post Title ".time());
    $NewPost->setLabels("Post Label1");
    $NewPost->setContent("Post Content!!!!");
    $NewPost->setCustomMetaData("Custom Meta Data ".time());

    try
    {
    $nposts = $posts->insert("xx3606012xxx592612750xx",$NewPost);
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
       print_r($e);
    }
```

from the official api documentation i am unable to find / understand a way to attach images into posts.
https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/reference/posts/insert

Edit-1:
one thought came into mind is that i can convert the images into `base64` encoding and add it into post content, but that would make huge chunk of code depending on the size of the image and that might crash the browser!

Comment: https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/reference/posts/insert says "in the request, supply a Posts resource." And https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/reference/posts#resource has an images property. Therefore I'd expect your `$NewPost` object is likely to have a matching property.

Comment: Thanks ADyson, can you show me with example code?

Comment: I've never used this specific object. That is just my inference based on how Google's PHP API client works in general. If you're unsure, consult examples in the library's official documentation initially, and/or consult the source code to see what it expects you to provide to it. https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client, https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client-services, https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client-services/blob/master/src/Google/Service/Blogger/Post.php . I'd imagine `public function setImages` is of interest to you.

Comment: And then https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client-services/blob/master/src/Google/Service/Blogger/PostImages.php . It looks like you have to upload the images separately (perhaps to google photos), and then your blog post data just contains URLs which point to those images.

Comment: Thanks ADyson, i guess you are right, becuase the link you have provided in the very first comment says the image property contains urls. so this means i have to first upload images into google photos and then get those url into image post?

Comment: It looks like it yes. Possibly you could alternatively upload them to some completely separate 3rd-party store such as imgur or one of those. But yes you need upload them somewhere first, get the URL to each one of them, and then pass those URLs to your blog post.